# Error al abrir un archivo de excel desde visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

Buen dia.

Tengo el promble al darle **Imprimir Fomulario** me arroja el siguiente error:
**'Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))'** el error lo arroja en la siguiente linea:

```
Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\FormularioFA\Formato\FA_Formulario.xlsx")
```

y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    Private Sub ImprimirFormulario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Handles ImprimirFormulario.Click
    'Try

    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\FormularioFA\Formato\FA_Formulario.xlsx")
        Dim ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        app.Visible = True
        ws.cells(8, 7).Value = FA_Elaborated.Text
        ws.cells(9, 7).Value = ID_Employee.Text
        ws.cells(10, 7).Value = Work_Shift.Text
        ws.cells(11, 7).Value = ID_FA.Text
        ws.cells(12, 7).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        ws.cells(17, 3).Value = Test_Station.Text
        ws.cells(19, 3).Value = Failure_Reported.Text
        ws.cells(23, 5).Value = Component_Location.Text
        ws.cells(24, 5).Value = Supplier.Text
        ws.cells(25, 5).Value = Supplier_SerialNumber.Text
        ws.cells(26, 5).Value = Supplier_PartNumber.Text
        ws.cells(27, 5).Value = DateCode.Text
        ws.cells(31, 5).Value = SerialNumber_82Level.Text
        ws.cells(32, 5).Value = PartNumber_82Level.Text
        ws.cells(36, 5).Value = Assembly_SerialNumber.Text
        ws.cells(37, 5).Value = Assembly_PartNumber.Text
        ws.cells(50, 3).Value = Failure_Mode.Text
        ws.cells(59, 3).Value = Debug_Steps.Text
        ws.cells(96, 2).Value = Failure_Mode.Text

        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(PictureBox2.Image)
        ws.cells(74, 2).select
        ws.paste

        FA_Elaborated.Text = ""
        ID_Employee.Text = ""
        Work_Shift.Text = Nothing
        ID_FA.Text = ID_FA.Text + 1
        Test_Station.Text = ""
        Failure_Reported.Text = ""
        Component_Location.Text = ""
        Supplier.Text = ""
        Supplier_SerialNumber.Text = ""
        Supplier_PartNumber.Text = ""
        DateCode.Text = ""
        SerialNumber_82Level.Text = ""
        PartNumber_82Level.Text = ""
        Assembly_PartNumber.Text = ""
        Assembly_SerialNumber.Text = ""
        Failure_Mode.Text = ""
        Debug_Steps.Text = ""
        Conclution.Text = ""
        PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
        FA_Elaborated.Focus()
        'Catch ex As Exception
    '   MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Échale un ojo al siguiente enlace: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/320369/bug-old-format-or-invalid-type-library-error-when-automating-excel. Tiene pinta de que tienes una versión inglesa de excel.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

```
    Private Sub ImprimirFormulario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    ImprimirFormulario.Click
    'Try

    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    app.UserControl = True
    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
    Dim wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\FormularioFA\Formato\FA_Formulario.xlsx")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    Dim ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    app.Visible = True
    app.UserControl = True
    ws.cells(8, 7).Value = FA_Elaborated.Text
    ws.cells(9, 7).Value = ID_Employee.Text
    ws.cells(10, 7).Value = Work_Shift.Text
    ws.cells(11, 7).Value = ID_FA.Text
    ws.cells(12, 7).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    ws.cells(17, 3).Value = Test_Station.Text
    ws.cells(19, 3).Value = Failure_Reported.Text
    ws.cells(23, 5).Value = Component_Location.Text
    ws.cells(24, 5).Value = Supplier.Text
    ws.cells(25, 5).Value = Supplier_SerialNumber.Text
    ws.cells(26, 5).Value = Supplier_PartNumber.Text
    ws.cells(27, 5).Value = DateCode.Text
    ws.cells(31, 5).Value = SerialNumber_82Level.Text
    ws.cells(32, 5).Value = PartNumber_82Level.Text
    ws.cells(36, 5).Value = Assembly_SerialNumber.Text
    ws.cells(37, 5).Value = Assembly_PartNumber.Text
    ws.cells(50, 3).Value = Failure_Mode.Text
    ws.cells(59, 3).Value = Debug_Steps.Text
    ws.cells(96, 2).Value = Failure_Mode.Text

    Clipboard.Clear()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(PictureBox2.Image)
    ws.cells(74, 2).select
    ws.paste

    FA_Elaborated.Text = ""
    ID_Employee.Text = ""
    Work_Shift.Text = Nothing
    ID_FA.Text = ID_FA.Text + 1
    Test_Station.Text = ""
    Failure_Reported.Text = ""
    Component_Location.Text = ""
    Supplier.Text = ""
    Supplier_SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Supplier_PartNumber.Text = ""
    DateCode.Text = ""
    SerialNumber_82Level.Text = ""
    PartNumber_82Level.Text = ""
    Assembly_PartNumber.Text = ""
    Assembly_SerialNumber.Text = ""
    Failure_Mode.Text = ""
    Debug_Steps.Text = ""
    Conclution.Text = ""
    PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
    FA_Elaborated.Focus()
        'Catch ex As Exception
    '   MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Usando la informacion que me proporciono @fergush

Saludos...